# bluebird promises - how to return a promise out of callback?

Tags: javascript, cookies, promise

Let's say I have the following function

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: 'google.com'}, callbackFn);
```

where callbackFn should return all the cookies available

now I have a big `main()` function (I must have this function) and this function must return the cookies of the given page(as a promise).

How should I do it?

Comment: you should add what the signature of `callbackFn` is. If it is `callback(err, cookies)`, or just `callback(cookies)`

Comment: @t.niese It just returns an array of cookies: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll
(I guess it's not supposed to fail, being local)

Comment: ok then its like `dystroy` has written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
function main(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve/*, reject*/) {
         chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: 'google.com'}, resolve);
    });
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
main().then(function(cookies) {
     // eat cookies
});
```

Comment: this is something like custom .promisify() method? I tried that, but it threw an error...

Comment: What threw an error ? `new Promise` ? What error ?

Comment: Unhandled rejection (<[{"domain":".l.facebook.com","expirati...>, no stack trace) (tried on "facebook.com" instead of "google.com")... The Bluebird.promisify(chrome.cookie.getAll) threw that. now i'm gonna try your solution :)

Comment: @Novellizator It's normal: `promisify` expects the passed function to return an error as first argument to the callback. So the array of cookies was interpreted as an error by BlueBird (which means you could have got it in using `throw` if you wanted to play real dirty)

Comment: @Novellizator `promisify`  will only work if the callback is in the form `err, result`

Comment: @dystroy now I get Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined. Have the same code only instead of new Promise I have new Bluebird. What is the matter? :(

Comment: What ? Are you testing in a Chrome extension ?

Comment: oh sorry, wait. chrome.cookieS is the right way. my fault, thanks

Comment: Oh yes, didn't check the spelling when copy-pasting